# Golang using aws lambda error: InvokeInput not declared by package lambda

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I'm trying to call another lambda function using the following code:

```golang
sess := session.Must(
  session.NewSessionWithOptions(
    session.Options{
      SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    },
  ),
)

svc := lambda.New(sess, &aws.Config{Region: aws.String("ap-east-1")})

result, err := svc.Invoke(&lambda.InvokeInput{
  FunctionName: aws.String(os.Getenv("testLambdaFunc")),
  Payload:      []byte(req.Body),
})
```

But there are two errors

```
New not declared by package lambda
```

and

```
InvokeInput not declared by package lambda
```

I've tried to initialize the **go.mod** file, but it doesn't fix both of the errors.

Any ideas?

The imports of my `main.go` file:

```
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "pkg/log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
```

And the `go.mod` file

```
module somefunc

go 1.16

require (
    github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go v1.27.0
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.40.59
    pkg/log v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
)

replace pkg/log => ./../../go/common/pkg/log
```

Comment: Can you share your imports and your `go.mod` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code snipped, it looks as if you are using the AWS SDK for Go V2. It is recommended to use the AWS SDK for Go V2 (please review the [Migrating to the AWS SDK for Go V2 documentation](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/migrating/)).

Please initialize a Go Modules project (as described on the SDK's [Github page](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2)):

```
mkdir YOUR-PROJECT
cd YOUR-PROJECT
go mod init YOUR-PROJECT
```

Add the dependencies as follows:

```
go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws
go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config
go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/lambda
```

The above should give you a working project where the dependencies for the SDK packages will resolve.

The corresponding V2 code will look something like the following:

```
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
    config.WithRegion("us-east-1"),
)
if err != nil {
    [...]
}

svc := lambda.NewFromConfig(cfg)

result, err := svc.Invoke(context.TODO(),
    &lambda.InvokeInput{
        FunctionName: aws.String(os.Getenv("testLambdaFunc")),
        Payload: []byte(req.Body),
    },
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is useful for me. I find out that my project is using two different libraries: 
1. `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/lambda`
2. `github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda`

Comment: So why did this error happens, because of the function that I should use library 1, I used library 2.